# Query for product history in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new to SQL. I have a table with several columns. One of them is filled with the actual serial nomber of a product, and other is filled with the previous serial number.

I need a query that, given the actual S/N or Product name, it returns the changes history.

Example:

```
ProdName   Actual SN   Prev SN    
------------------------------
P1           681         300    
P2           123         123    
P3           555         123    
P4           777         555    
P5           999         999    
P6           666         888    
P7           333         111    
P8           987         777
```

I need to know the product history. For example **P8** History would be:

```
ProdName    SN    
----------------
P8          987    
P4          777    
P3          555    
P2          123
```

(it should stop when 'Actual SN' == 'Prev SN')

Thank you!

Comment: Does ProdName contain unique values? If not, please provide an example with several rows with same ProdName. By the way, you say, that it should stop, when prev = actual, but what will happen when there is no such condition or with circular references? I suppose you can look for recursive CTE to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Alex!

I did not think about your question before. The thing is that ProdName has not unique values, so I´ll have to do the query using the SN, wich is unique.

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved by using a recursive CTE that loops through the parent/children pairs.

```
WITH RCTE_PRODUCT_HISTORY AS
(
    -- seeding the recursive
    SELECT ProdName, [Actual SN], [Prev SN]
    , [Actual SN] AS StartSN
    , 0 AS Lvl
    FROM YourProductHistoryTable
    WHERE ProdName = 'P8'

    UNION ALL

    -- looping the recursive till nothing new is found, or condition is met
    SELECT t.ProdName, t.[Actual SN], t.[Prev SN]
    , c.StartSN
    , c.Lvl + 1
    FROM RCTE_PRODUCT_HISTORY c
    JOIN YourProductHistoryTable t
      ON t.[Actual SN] = c.[Prev SN]
    WHERE t.[Prev SN] != c.StartSN
      AND t.[Actual SN] != c.[Actual SN]
)
SELECT ProdName, [Actual SN] AS SN
FROM RCTE_PRODUCT_HISTORY
ORDER BY Lvl
```

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ca49e3f80962b826b0150e461cd49ff4)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion:

```
with cte as (
    select ProdName, ActualSN, PrevSN, 0 lvl from mytable where ProdName = 'P8'
    union all
    select t.ProdName, t.ActualSN, t.prevSN, lvl + 1
    from mytable t
    inner join cte c on c.PrevSN = t.ActualSN and c.PrevSN != c.ActualSN
)
select ProdName, ActualSN SN from cte order by lvl
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d6d4cc697aa1799116a6681a19277626)**:

```
ProdName | SN 
:------- | :--
P8       | 987
P4       | 777
P3       | 555
P2       | 123
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query.

```
WITH cte_Product([Productname], [ActualSN],[PreviousSN],RN) 
AS (
    SELECT * ,0 as RN
    From [dbo].[SN]
    where [Productname]='p8'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  s.*,RN+1 from [dbo].[SN] s
    INNER JOIN  cte_Product cn on s.ActualSN=cn.[PreviousSN]
    and cn.ActualSN !=cn.[PreviousSN]    
)
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    cte_Product
```